# Time taken for a block to slide down a composite slope

Tags: algorithms, classical-mechanics

Suppose you had a list of numbers $[y_1, y_2,\ldots,y_n]$ that define the $y$-coordinates of $n$ points in space that are joined up to make a composite "slope" made of various line segments; the horizontal separation of each point is $x$ units.

Would it be possible to devise a method/algorithm to symbolically calculate the time taken for a block to frictionlessly slide down the ramp? I have considered using GPE/KE but am not too sure what to do at each change of direction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: No friction, so the block can't lose speed; either it bounces due to hitting the angle or you make the simplifying assumption that it instantaneously changes direction. If this was actually a model of a curved ramp with piecewise linear interpolation then the instantaneous change makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; this is modelling a curved ramp so instantaneous change would apply. What would happen to the particle's velocity in this case? Would you just resolve it in that direction or would you just assume same magnitude but in a different direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose a point-mass $m$ under the influence of gravity is constrained to slide without friction along a piecewise-linear path having no point higher than the starting point. Let there be $N$ segments joining $N+1$ end-points $P_i=(x_i,y_i) (i=0,\ldots,N).$

Let $t_i$ be the time at which the point-mass is at the point $(x_i,y_i) (i=0,\ldots,N$), taking $t_0=0$; thus, $0=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_N,$ and we seek an algorithm for $t_N.$

By conservation of energy,
$${1\over 2}m{\dot s}^2 + mgy = mgy_0$$
where $s(t)$ is the total arc length along the path already traversed at time $t,$ and dot denotes the time-derivative; hence,

> $$\dot s(t) = \sqrt{2g\left(y_0-y(t)\right)}.\tag{1}$$

On the other hand, for $t\in[t_{k},t_{k+1}],$ we have the equation of motion
$$\ddot{s}(t)=g_k$$
where $g_k$ is the component of the gravitational acceleration in the direction of motion along the segment $\overline{P_kP_{k+1}}$, i.e.,

$$g_k= g\,\text{sgn}(y_k-y_{k+1})\,\sin{\theta_k}=g\,{y_k-y_{k+1}\over\sqrt{(y_{k+1}-y_k)^2 + (x_{k+1}-x_k)^2}}$$
where $\theta_k$ is the acute angle between $\overline{P_kP_{k+1}}$ and the horizontal. (The sign of $g_k$ is such that $g_k>0$ when the mass is *descending* and $g_k<0$ when *ascending*.)

Integration then gives, for $t\in[t_{k},t_{k+1}],$
$$\dot s(t)=g_kt+A_k$$
where $A_k$ is a constant; therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\dot s(t_{k+1})&=g_kt_{k+1}+A_k\\
\dot s(t_{k})&=g_kt_{k}+A_k
\end{align}$$
Taking the difference of these and rearranging, we find that the travel-time on segment $\overline{P_kP_{k+1}}$ is 
$$t_{k+1}-t_k={\dot s(t_{k+1})-\dot s(t_{k})\over g_k}
$$
hence the total travel-time is

> $$\begin{align}
> t_N &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(t_{k+1}-t_k)\\[2ex]
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{\dot s(t_{k+1})-\dot s(t_{k})\over g_k}\\[2ex]
> &=\sqrt{2\over g}\ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}{ \sqrt{y_0-y_{k+1}}-\sqrt{y_0-y_k}  \over \text{sgn}(y_k-y_{k+1})\,\sin{\theta_k} }\quad\text{(from Eq.(1))}\\[2ex]
> &=\sqrt{2\over g}\ \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\left( { \sqrt{(y_{k+1}-y_k)^2 + (x_{k+1}-x_k)^2 }  \over y_k-y_{k+1} }\left( \sqrt{y_0-y_{k+1}}-\sqrt{y_0-y_k} \right)\right)
> \end{align}$$

**Example** (aligned segments):

If all the segments have the same slope, then all $\theta_k=\theta$ (say), and the segments constitute a single overall line segment. The sum then telescopes to
$$t_N =  \sqrt{2\over g}\ {\sqrt{y_0-y_N}\over\sin{\theta}}=\sqrt{2l\over g\sin{\theta}}$$ 
where $l$ is the combined length of all the segments. This is the correct result for a mass sliding a distance $l$ without friction down a plane inclined at angle $\theta$, as can be easily confirmed by twice integrating the equation of motion $\ddot s = g\,\sin{\theta}$ and applying the appropriate boundary conditions to get $s(t)={g\over 2}\,(\sin{\theta})\,t^2,$ hence $l={g\over 2}\,(\sin{\theta})\,t_N^2.$

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive answer, and your time. If some of the gradients of the segments are positive, besides the case where the points are higher than the initial point and the particle does not reach the end, would that change anything at all?

Comment: @user83893939  Good point -- under that proviso, the same equations apply. (I'll edit accordingly.) BTW, I've programmed this algorithm in Sage and confirmed that it works correctly. For example, it correctly solves the piecewise-linear "discretized" [Brachistochrone problem](http://faculty.madisoncollege.edu/alehnen/brach/MathFest2008-Brachistochrone.html) -- converging nicely to the known answer as N increases, even when both positive and negative gradients occur.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, this is in fact the application I was testing and my program also approximated the time for the cycloid correctly.